# Custom Rally Charts w/ Series (similar to clustered Excel graph)

Tags: graph, rally, trending, code-rally

is it possible to create a custom chart/graph in Rally of a bar chart and then display a series?  i want to trend a count of stories over time for each release.

i've tried using regular charts but doesn't seem like that is a capability of rally

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but in case you're still looking, it is possible to have multiple plots in the same Rally Chart.

In the `chartData` config, you can pass multiple values to the `series` property like so:

```
chartData: {
  categories: ['cat 1', 'cat 2', etc...],
  series: [{
    Name: 'Series 1',
    data: yourSeriesData1,
    type: 'column'
  }, {
    Name: 'Series 2',
    data: yourSeriesData2,
    type: 'spline'
  }]
}
```